# doing left join on tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, the first table (table1) contains id, dat_beg, period, dat_end. Second table (table2) contains multiple columns including the **cod_client and cod_contract**. I want to perform a left join with the mentioned tables. 
Please does anyone know what is wrong in my code?

Thank you in advance,

```
select id, DATE_TRUNC('day', table1.dat_beg) as date, s1, cod_client, sum(perid) as sum_period from (
select id, table1.dat_end, x, table1.dat_beg , 
(case when TRIM(x) like 'cat/%' then 'cat'
when TRIM(x) like 'fol/%' then 'follower'
else 'unknown'
end) as s1,
(extract(epoch from (table1.dat_end - table1.dat_beg)))/60 as sum_period
from table1 left join table2 on table1.id = table2.cod_contract
where table1.dat_end < '2262-04-11' and table1.dat_beg >= '2019-01-10'
) X
group by table1.id, table1.s1, table1.date
```

Comment: What is the current output and the desired one. Does it join if you remove LEFT keyword?

Comment: now im having the error in the clause **from**. @jlandercy

Comment: @jlandercy without left it does'nt work too .

Comment: You need to fix your group by clause. it should be group by id, 
       Date_trunc('day', table1.dat_beg), 
       s1, 
       cod_client

Comment: i have always the same error.

Comment: What error you are getting.

Comment: ERROR: Missing entry of the FROM clause for the "table1" table @AnkitBajpai thank you for your response .

Comment: You should post desired output along with full table schema

Comment: @AkhileshMishra i want to join the two tables where table1.id == table2.cod_client. I don't know how to give more details. Please tell me if not clear

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a whole host of problems with this query. I'm going to post what I think might work, then the bits I'm not sure about.

```
SELECT 
    x.id, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', x.dat_beg) AS date_day, 
    x.s1, 
    x.cod_client, 
    SUM(x.sum_period) AS sum_period 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            id, 
            table1.dat_beg, 
            table2.cod_client,
            CASE 
                WHEN TRIM(x) LIKE 'cat/%' THEN 'cat'
                WHEN TRIM(x) LIKE 'fol/%' THEN 'follower'
                ELSE 'unknown'
            END AS s1,
            (EXTRACT(epoch FROM (table1.dat_end - table1.dat_beg)))/60 AS sum_period
        FROM 
            table1 
            LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.cod_contract
        WHERE 
            table1.dat_end < '2262-04-11' 
            AND table1.dat_beg >= '2019-01-10'
    ) x
GROUP BY 
    x.id, 
    DATE_TRUNC('day', x.dat_beg), 
    x.s1, 
    x.cod_client
```

Problems:

- cod_client isn't included in the sub-query, so I guessed it came from `table2`?
- you referenced `table1` outside the sub-query, where it has no meaning. I changed this to `x` instead;
- you had many extra (unnecessary (really!)) brackets;
- there were columns in your `x` sub-query that weren't used in the outer query;
- you were summing something called `perid`, but that didn't exist anywhere, I guessed it was meant to be `sum_period`?

**EDIT**

[Demo on Fiddle](http://Above%20query%20is%20not%20having%20any%20syntax%20problem.%20This%20error%20is%20due%20to%20lack%20of%20information%20in%20the%20question.%20I%20have%20ed)

Comment: Above query is not having any syntax problem. This error may be due to lack of information in the question. You can check it on Fiddle [Click Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wWQLRUYEX3r3ypMrEmJt1K/0)

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct except GROUP BY clause and SUM function -

```
SELECT id, 
       Date_trunc('day', table1.dat_beg) AS date, 
       s1, 
       cod_client, 
       Sum(sum_period)                        AS perid 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               table1.dat_end, 
               x, 
               table1.dat_beg, 
               ( CASE 
                   WHEN Trim(x) LIKE 'cat/%' THEN 'cat' 
                   WHEN Trim(x) LIKE 'fol/%' THEN 'follower' 
                   ELSE 'unknown' 
                 END ) 
               AS s1, 
               ( Extract(epoch FROM ( table1.dat_end - table1.dat_beg )) ) / 60 
               AS 
                      sum_period 
        FROM   table1 
               LEFT JOIN table2 
                      ON table1.id = table2.cod_contract 
        WHERE  table1.dat_end < '2262-04-11' 
               AND table1.dat_beg >= '2019-01-10') X 
GROUP  BY id, 
       Date_trunc('day', table1.dat_beg), 
       s1, 
       cod_client
```